# Detecting Collisions with a sprites in LinkedList

Tags: java, android, andengine

Hey guys so here is my dilemma.

I have a Animated sprite that i am using and using an Animation Listener to know when the animation is finished or on its last frame.

when the animation is on its last frame, i would like to remove whatever object it is colliding with.

So here is the issue i am having right now:

I am using a TimeHandler to detect the collision but the problem is i have a random amount of removable objects added to the game, and i add them to a LinkedList as they are added to the scene during load time.

Then in my TimeHandler i try to detect the collision like this;

```
   mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(.005f, true,
        new ITimerCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

            if (frames == 1) {

              if (woodSprites.hasNext()) {

                Sprite sprite = woodSprites.next();
                if (bombSprite.collidesWith(sprite)) {
                  Log.e("Frame", "Collision");
                  removeFace(sprite);

                }
              }
            }

          }

        }));
```

The problem with this approach is that if the the bomb sprite is colliding with a removable sprite that isnt next in the Iterator then it wont detect a collision and nothing will happen. I need to be able to remove that particular removable sprite when it is having an collision

Does anyone know or have any suggestions for getting this to work?

Comment: How many items are in your LinkedList? Would it be too expensive to iterate through the items and call collidesWith for each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason to use the TimerHandler, it could perform very badly since it could just keep missing the right frame. Are you doing it to improve performance? Try this code:

```
mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

    @Override
    public void reset() {}

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if (frames == 1) {
            for (Sprite s : woodSprites) {
                if (bombSprite.collidesWith(s)) {
                    removeFace(s);
                }
            }
    }
});
```

I think the performance hit should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you don't surf through the List, and that's why you're trying to detect collision with only one element. Try:

```
while (woodSprites.hasNext()) {
    if (bombSprite.collidesWith(woodSprites)) {
        Log.e("Frame", "Collision");
        removeFace(woodSprites);
    }
}
```